# Why does the order of the codes for different equations affect the final appearance of the equation

Tags: equations

When I put my code in the following order, I would get the equation on the right (which is what I want):

[image]

However, if the 2 equation codes on the left are switched, I would get a new type of equation (see the right of the picture):
[image]

Why does that happen? How should I avoid this?

*The original code:*

```
\begin{math}

%\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{0} -x\cos(n\pi x)} dx + \int_0^1 x\cos(n\pi x) dx

\frac{1}{2} + (-1)^1 (\frac{2^{-1} x^0}{1}) = \frac{1}{2} + (-1)\frac{1}{2} = 0

\end{math}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Screenshots of code are not helpful since we can't copy and paste your code to try it. Also, you can't have blank lines in math mode which should be giving you errors and is likely to blame for what's going wrong.

Comment: you must get errors from the blank line in math, after any error the pdf output is not intended to be usable.  It looks like you should use `displaymath` not `math` (or more simply use `\[...\]` and remove `\displaystyle` and the blank lines.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments?!